# Compute gradients w.r.t. the values of embedding vectors in PyTorch

Tags: nlp, lstm, chatbot, pytorch, word-embedding

I am trying to train a dual encoder LSTM model for a chatbot using PyTorch.

I defined two classes: the Encoder class defines the LSTM itself and the Dual_Encoder class applies the Encoder to both context and response utterances that I am trying to train on:

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, 
                 input_size, 
                 hidden_size, 
                 vocab_size, 
                 num_layers = 1, 
                 num_directions = 1, 
                 dropout = 0, 
                 bidirectional = False,
                 rnn_type = 'lstm'): 

                 super(Encoder, self).__init__()

                 self.input_size = input_size
                 self.hidden_size = hidden_size
                 self.vocab_size = vocab_size
                 self.num_layers = 1
                 self.num_directions = 1
                 self.dropout = 0,
                 self.bidirectional = False

                 self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, input_size, sparse = False, padding_idx = 0)
                 self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.input_size, self.hidden_size, self.num_layers, batch_first=False, dropout = dropout, bidirectional=False).cuda()

                 self.init_weights()

    def init_weights(self):
        init.orthogonal(self.lstm.weight_ih_l0)

        init.uniform(self.lstm.weight_hh_l0, a=-0.01, b=0.01)

        embedding_weights = torch.FloatTensor(self.vocab_size, self.input_size).cuda()
        init.uniform(embedding_weights, a = -0.25, b= 0.25)

        id_to_vec, emb_dim = create_id_to_vec('/data/train_shuffled_onethousand.csv','/data/glove.6B.100d.txt')

        for id, vec in id_to_vec.items():
            embedding_weights[id] = vec

        del self.embedding.weight
        self.embedding.weight = nn.Parameter(embedding_weights)
        self.embedding.weight.requires_grad = True

        #self.embedding.weight.data.copy_(torch.from_numpy(self.embedding_weights))

    def forward(self, inputs):
        embeddings = self.embedding(inputs)
        outputs, hiddens = self.lstm(embeddings)
        return outputs, hiddens

#%%

class DualEncoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, encoder):
         super(DualEncoder, self).__init__()
         self.encoder = encoder
         self.number_of_layers = 1
         #h_0 (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size): 
         #tensor containing the initial hidden state for each element in the batch.
         #dual_hidden_size = self.encoder.hidden_size * self.encoder.num_directions

         M = torch.FloatTensor(self.encoder.hidden_size, self.encoder.hidden_size).cuda()

         init.normal(M)

         self.M = nn.Parameter(M, requires_grad = True)

    def forward(self, contexts, responses):
        #output (seq_len, batch, hidden_size * num_directions): 
        #tensor containing the output features (h_t) from the last layer 
        #of the RNN, for each t. 

        #h_n (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size): 
        #tensor containing the hidden state for t=seq_len
        context_out, context_hn = self.encoder(contexts)

        response_out, response_hn = self.encoder(responses)

        scores_list = []

        y_preds = None

        for e in range(999): 
            context_h = context_out[e][-1].view(1, self.encoder.hidden_size)
            response_h = response_out[e][-1].view(self.encoder.hidden_size,1)


            dot_var = torch.mm(torch.mm(context_h, self.M), response_h)[0][0]

            dot_tensor = dot_var.data
            dot_tensor.cuda()

            score = torch.sigmoid(dot_tensor)
            scores_list.append(score)

        y_preds_tensor = torch.stack(scores_list).cuda()  
        y_preds = autograd.Variable(y_preds_tensor).cuda()

        return y_preds 

#%% TRAINING

torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = False
#%%
vocab = create_vocab('/data/train_shuffled_onethousand.csv')
vocab_len = len(vocab)
emb_dim = get_emb_dim('/data/glove.6B.100d.txt')
#%%

encoder_model = Encoder(
        input_size = emb_dim,
        hidden_size = 300,
        vocab_size = vocab_len)

encoder_model.cuda()
#%%
dual_encoder = DualEncoder(encoder_model)

dual_encoder.cuda()
#%%
loss_func = torch.nn.BCELoss()

loss_func.cuda()

learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 100
#batch_size = 50

optimizer = optim.Adam(dual_encoder.parameters(),
                       lr = learning_rate)
#%%
for i in range(epochs):

    context_matrix, response_matrix, y = make_matrices('/data/train_shuffled_onethousand.csv')

    context_matrix = autograd.Variable(context_matrix, requires_grad=True).cuda()

    response_matrix = autograd.Variable(response_matrix, requires_grad=True).cuda()

    y_label = y.cuda()

    y_preds = dual_encoder(context_matrix, response_matrix)

    loss = loss_func(y_preds, y_label)

    if i % 10 == 0:
        print("Epoch: ", i, ", Loss: ", loss.data[0])

    #evaluation metrics...

    dual_encoder.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm(dual_encoder.parameters(), 10)

    optimizer.step()
```

The following error occurs:

```
2018-01-06 06:07:02,148 INFO - result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
2018-01-06 06:07:02,148 INFO - File "all_scripts.py", line 258, in forward
2018-01-06 06:07:02,148 INFO - context_out, context_hn = self.encoder(contexts)
2018-01-06 06:07:02,149 INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 325, in __call__
2018-01-06 06:07:02,149 INFO - result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
2018-01-06 06:07:02,149 INFO - File "all_scripts.py", line 229, in forward
2018-01-06 06:07:02,149 INFO - embeddings = self.embedding(inputs)
2018-01-06 06:07:02,150 INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 325, in __call__
2018-01-06 06:07:02,150 INFO - result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
2018-01-06 06:07:02,150 INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 103, in forward
2018-01-06 06:07:02,150 INFO - self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse
2018-01-06 06:07:02,150 INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/_functions/thnn/sparse.py", line 40, in forward
2018-01-06 06:07:02,151 INFO - assert not ctx.needs_input_grad[0], "Embedding doesn't " \
2018-01-06 06:07:02,151 INFO - AssertionError: Embedding doesn't compute the gradient w.r.t. the indices
```

I do understand why the problem occurs (surely it makes no sense to compute the gradient w.r.t. the indices).
But I do not understand how to adjust the code so that it computes the gradients w.r.t. the content values of the embedding vectors.

All help highly appreciated!

(Also see the [thread in the PyTorch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/embedding-returns-an-error-that-i-dont-understand/1072/5) forum)

Answer (score 2):

After some extensive adjustments, the code works now. The problem was not only the embedding initialization. See [my github repo](https://github.com/Janinanu/UDC_Chatbot/blob/master/PyTorch_Dialog_System_Notebook.ipynb) for the improved code.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I updated the link, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are deleting the weights of the embedding layer. If you want to initialize the embedding weights, you should do:

```
self.embedding.weight.data.copy_(torch.from_numpy(self.embedding_weights))
```

You have commented out the above line but that is the best way to initialize the embedding weights.

Comment: I tried two ways of initializing the embedding weights, the one that I used in my code above and the one that I commented out. As far as I can tell, it turned out that that was not the reason for the error. After some extensive adjustments, the code now works. I will post the code in my answer.